# Type of Python data type list is either list or tuple depending on usage but why

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

```
>>> lst = [[-2, -1], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> lst
   [[-2, -1], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> print (*lst)
[-2, -1] [0, 1, 2]

>>> print (type(lst))
<class 'list'>
```

So the type for `lst` is here is `list`

In the context of a function call - I am not sure why it is still not a list. The statement print `(type(lst))` prints: `<class 'tuple'>.` Within the function, why is `lst` not a `list`?

```
def mymap(func, *lst):
    res = []
    print (func)    
    print (*lst)
    print (type(lst))
    print (list(zip(*lst)))
    for args in list((zip(*lst))):           
        res.append(func(*args))
        #return (res) 
    return (res)
ts = mymap(pow, [-2, -1], [0, 1, 2])

print (ts)
```

Comment: why do you expect `lst` to be a list?

Comment: The `*args` syntax puts the arguments in a tuple. It doesn't matter that those arguments are themselves lists.

Comment: @hop - I don't expect `lst` to be a list - but the result is in-consistent between printing `*lst` from the command line vs `*lst` as the 2nd argument in function `mymap`. The latter case seems to force a type conversion....

Comment: Again, _why_ should `lst` in your function contain anything _but_ a tuple?

Comment: It is *not* inconsistent. You are *unpacking* a list-of-lists into the `print` function. In your function defintion, you are using the variable-argument syntax, which will always use a tuple to aggregate the arguments. There *is no type conversion going on anywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are [*unpacking* a sequence into several parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) that are then given to the function (`print` in this case).

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*numbers)
1 2 3
```

is the exact same as

```
>>> print(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2])
1 2 3
```

In your second example you are using an [arbitrary parameter list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) where several arguments are packed into a tuple.

Two different things, two different outcomes. There is no inconsistency.